# Autosuggestion with solr

Tags: solr, autocomplete

I'm implementing auto-suggestion in a web page (ASP.NET MVC) with solr and have understood that there are a number of ways to do this, including:

- jQuery Autocomplete, Suggester, facets or NGramFilterFactory.
- Which one is the fastest one to use for auto-suggestion?

Any good information about this?

Comment: All of the tools you mention are meant for different purposes, and in most cases complement each other. If you could narrow down your question to a problem, it would help, otherwise the question is too broad.

Comment: I want to have the fastest posible autocomplete solution for a input text box in a web page. What solution is the fastest for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a good look at 'AJAX Solr' at https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr .

AJAX Solr has autocomplete widget among other things.  Demo site - http://evolvingweb.github.io/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.html .

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at addressing your need, with this disclaimer:

'Fastest' is a very vague term, and extends to a broader spectrum, i.e browser used, page weight, network etc. These need to be optimized outside the search implementation, if need be.

I would go for the straight-forward implementation and then optimize it based on performance stats

Ok, now to the implementation, at a high level:

1) Create a Solr index with a field having an `NGramTokenizerFactory` tokenizer.
- to reduce chatter, keep minLength of NGram to be 2, and fire autosuggest with `minLength =2`

2) Depending on technology used, you can either route search requests through your application, or hit Solr directly. Hitting Solr directly could be faster (Ref AjaxSolr as mentioned already).

3) Use something like Jquery-ui to have an autosuggest implemtation, backed with ajax requsts to Solr.

Here are couple of reference implementations:

- http://isotope11.com/blog/autocomplete-with-solr-and-jquery-ui
- https://gist.github.com/pduey/2648514

**Note** that there are similar implementation that work well for live sites, so I would be tempted to try this out and see if there is still a bottleneck, and not tempted to do any premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

'AJAX Solr' has limitations with respect to autosuggestions as it provides only word level suggestions. Internally it uses faceting to generate them.

But SOLR provides different suggesters which we can leverage to generate intelligent autosuggestions(words/phrase)
Checkout this blog post to know more. 
http://lucidworks.com/blog/solr-suggester/

For implementation, you can use combination of suggesters(FST + Analyzing Infix) and jQuery autocomplete.